# rdlc Report RowNumber Issue when using rows Visiblity Hidden

Tags: c#, asp.net, rdlc

I am using Rdlc report. and i have applied row group in my rdlc report. I need the row number sequence excluding my hidden rows.  Here i will describe requirements,

Here the report is grouped by account Id.

---

### Account Id  : 101

### RowNumber |  Transactin Id   |   Amount

```
1     |   10100001          |   1200
2     |   10132658          |    1250
3     |   10155874          |   0
```

---

### Account Id  : 102

### RowNumber |  Transactin Id   |   Amount

```
4     |   10210001          |   1200
5     |   10212748          |    0
6     |   10200014          |   1000
```

---

After i apply the visibility hidden for zero valued rows , then I need the output like this,

---

### Account Id  : 101

### RowNumber |  Transactin Id   |   Amount

```
1     |   10100001          |   1200
2     |   10132658          |    1250
```

---

### Account Id  : 102

### RowNumber |  Transactin Id   |   Amount

```
3     |   10210001          |   1200
4     |   10200014          |   1000
```

---